# How cast Map(varchar,varchar) to string in trino?

Tags: sql, presto, trino

I have column with `Map(varchar,varch)` how to cast to string? Like `"key1"=>"value1","key2"=>"value2"`? Simple `CAST AS` does not work. `json_format` also does not work.

Answer (score 0):

You can cast it to JSON and then format it (formatting can be skipped in some cases):

```sql
select JSON_FORMAT(cast(map(array['a', 'b'], array['42', '777']) as JSON));
```

Output:

```
        _col0
----------------------
 {"a":"42","b":"777"}
```